# Remove percent sign on a percent field type

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I've been googling around but I couldnt find the way to remove the percent sign that the Form Component (Symfony) adds to the percent field type when rendering a form. I've found something related to redefined the percent widget but I couldn't get it how this works, neither where to change it.

This is what I found:

> You can overwrite the percent_widget block from the default layout to
>   something like this:

```
{% block percent_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% set type = type|default('text') %}
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock percent_widget %}
```

My current rendering code inside the template is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(edit_form.discountRate, 'Discount', {'label_attr':{'class':'col-sm-2 control-label'}}) }}
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            {{ form_widget(edit_form.discountRate, {'attr': {'class':'form-control'}}) }}
            <div class="input-group-addon">%</div>
        </div>                  
    </div>         
</div>
```

PD: Using the input-group class from boootstrap 3, I append that percent sign the way I like to render it, but how I delete the one that appends Symfony?

Comment: Could you show us the html output of the form? From my understanding the field type **percent** renders a text input, maybe your browser adds the % sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override the default form theme of symfony 2.

First, open your app/config/config.yml file, and edit the twig configuration to have something like this :

```
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form:
      resources:
      - YourBundleName:Form:my-form-theme.html.twig
```

(Its the `form.resources` part which is important). This configuration will tell Symfony 2 to use your custom theme.

You can also use `{% form_theme form 'YourBundleName:Form:my-form-theme.html.twig' %}` in your template if you don't want to add something in the config file, but I don't like to add this line in all my forms so I prefer to add it in global configuration.

Now you have to create a file `src/YourBundlePath/Resources/views/Form/my-form-theme.html.twig` with the following content :

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block percent_widget -%}
    {% set type = type|default('text') %}
    {{- block('form_widget_simple') -}}
{%- endblock percent_widget %}
```

And this should work.

If you open the theme file of Symfony 2 (`/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig`) you can see that there is :

```
{% block percent_widget -%}
    {% set type = type|default('text') %}
    {{- block('form_widget_simple') -}} %
{%- endblock percent_widget %}
```

I removed the "%" on the 3d line in the override.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You cant remove it, its one of cons of symfony form % char is hardcoded

```
{% block percent_widget -%}
    {% set type = type|default('text') %}
    {{- block('form_widget_simple') -}} %
{%- endblock percent_widget %}
```

You can write your own block, where You will remove %

Comment: Ofc you can, form theme override is a basic feature of Symfony 2.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to override the form theme in the template. There are [several ways](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming-in-twig) to do it.

I'm going to use the quickest.

Your template would end up like this:

```
{% form_theme edit_form _self %}

        {% block percent_widget %} 
            {% spaceless %} 
                {% set type = type|default('text') %} 
                {{ block('form_widget_simple') }} 
            {% endspaceless %} 
        {% endblock percent_widget %} 

<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(edit_form.discountRate, 'Discount', {'label_attr':{'class':'col-sm-2 control-label'}}) }}
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            {{ form_widget(edit_form.discountRate, {'attr': {'class':'form-control'}}) }}
            <div class="input-group-addon">%</div>
        </div>                  
    </div>         
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well no need to rewrite templates, the idea is to make a front removal with jQuery/JS. Most of the time your input is embedded in a div, and twig is generating something you like this :

`<div class="a">
<input ...>
%
</div>`

'%' text can be accessed and removed with native JS lastChild/removeChild functions :

`$('.a').removeChild($('.a').lastChild)` (jQuery/JS mix)

`document.getElementsByClassname(a).removeChild(document.getElementsByClassname(a).lastChild)` (plain vanilla JS)